# How to add string.join to foreach loop

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

I show the categories of my i'th product on the View, but I want to add a link and put commas between them.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span> @Model.Products[i].ProductName </span>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Products[i].ProductCategories)
            {
                <a href="/home/@item.ItemName"> @item.ItemName, </a>
            }
        </td>
   </tr>
```

It looks like this => Computer, Technology, Desktop,

I want this => Computer, Technology, Desktop

I don't want a comma in the last item

I can show it this way but I can't add `<a href=""></a>`

```
 <span>@string.Join(", ", Model.Products[i].ProductCategories.Select(p => p.Category.CategoryName))</span>
```

Comment: You could add a flag set to false before the loop and check it before outputting the comma before the link and set it to true at the end of the loop.  I'd even put the comma outside of the link anyway.

Comment: Is it `ItemName` or `CategoryName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use LINQ instead of `foreach`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span> @Model.Products[i].ProductName </span>
            @Html.Raw(String.Join(", ", Model.Products[i].ProductCategories.Select(category => $@"<a href=""/home/{Html.Encode(category.CategoryName)}"">{Html.Encode(category.CategoryName)}</a>")))
        </td>
   </tr>
```

But I won't say this is the most Razor way to do it. You should probably be using something like `Html.ActionLink` at this point instead of manually putting in the `a` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Using a brute force approach…

Have you considered using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop? Inside the `for` loop, if the loop index `j` is less than the collection count – 1, then add the comma.

Example, using your code structure…

```
@for (int j = 0; j < Model.Products[i].ProductCategories.Count(); j++) 
{
    If (j < Model.Products[i].ProductCategories.Count() – 1)
    {
        <a href="/home/@item.ItemName"> Model.Products[i].ProductCategories[j].ItemName, </a>
     }
     else
     {
         <a href="/home/@item.ItemName"> Model.Products[i].ProductCategories[j].ItemName</a>
     }
}
```

Comment: Calling `Count()` multiple times could be bad depending on what `ProductCategories` actually is.

Comment: @NetMage ... I am not that familiar with the language used here as it does not appear to be C#. What you say is true but could be fixed with a variable. But also my answer is missing the `j` index `@item.ItemName` needs to be index to `j`.... i may remove the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could do something like this. Could not test it, but should capture the gist.

```
<span>
    @string.Join(
        ", </a>", 
        Model.Products[i]
            .ProductCategories
            .Select(
                p => "<a href=\"" + p.Category.CategoryName + "\""))
    </a>
</span>
```